# How do I tail a log file without locking in perl

Tags: windows, perl, file, locking, tail

This is how I am doing it right now but it locks the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Env qw( $USERNAME );
use File::Tail;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = $ARGV[0];

print "$file\n";

my $fileTail = File::Tail->new( name=>$file, maxinterval=>5, tail=>-1);
my $line;

while ( defined( $line = $fileTail->read ) )
{
    print $line;
}

exit;
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aTail), it shouldn't be locking. What is your operating system though? I wonder if you are using Windows, although the shebang line suggests not. Some more details on your environment would therefore be helpful.

Comment: am using windows xp. the logs don't show up as often as they did when i was not running the above perl script. that made me think that it might be locking the log file

Comment: The documentation specifically says that $fileTail->read _will_ block.  If you don't want to block, then use $fileTail->select().  There is a full example in the link given in this answer.

Comment: @mark - *locking* ... not *blocking*. He says the logs aren't getting appended to when his perl script is tailing them.

Comment: Hmmm ... Windows XP ... that probably explains the issue. XP quite often behaves differently from a server class operating system when it comes to perl file handling modules that often rely on unix type behaviour under the hood. You could try dropping an email to the module's author which is present in the aforementioned documentation.

Comment: @Brian - Aha... I don't (ever) work on Microsoft platforms, so the idea that a process reading a file would essentially put a lock on it so that other processes couldn't write to it is utterly foreign.  I read the question and immediately mapped locking -> blocking.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Mark - neither do I, thankfully. I've just run into the imfamous "That file is open in another process" message when using it. Apparently the default method of opening a file includes an exclusive lock.

Answer (score 4):

Windows (or NTFS... or how Perl implements open on Windows... not exactly sure) has mandatory locking rolled into open().  If you open a file for reading, others will not be able to open it for writing.  If you open a file for writing, others will not be able to open it for reading or writing.

You're holding the file open for reading, so nobody can write to the log.  I think that's what's happening.  File::Tail probably doesn't account for this.  It's working at all because File::Tail seems to close and reopen the filehandle from time to time if it doesn't see any activity, it assumes it's been truncated or recreated.  This releases your lock and lets other files slip in to write.

You can test this by opening a file for reading with one Perl process, and then try to open it for appending by another.

I believe one way to deal with this is to open the log file using Windows specific functions that allow you to control the locking behavior.  [Win32::SharedFileOpen](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aSharedFileOpen) seems to be the thing.

```
fsopen(my $fh, $file, 'r', SH_DENYNO) or
    die "Can't read '$file' with no locks: $!\n";
```

That will open a file for reading with no locks.  Unfortunately, you're responsible for doing the rest of the work.  The [perlfaq](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-do-a-tail--f-in-perl?) might help.